# Does the compiler take care the useless codes like if(0)?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, compiler-optimization

Recently, I am compiling the ffmpeg codes under windows use the VS2010 with intel compiler.
For the following codes:

```
void ff_dcadsp_init(DCADSPContext *s)
{
    s->lfe_fir = dca_lfe_fir_c;
    if (ARCH_ARM) ff_dcadsp_init_arm(s);
}
```

the macro `ARCH_ARM` is defined as `0`.

When I compile it under linux, there is no function in `ff_dcadsp_init_arm()` in the object file, while it does under windows? So I want to make sure if the compiler will do something about the useless codes and how to set it for INTEL compiler.

Comment: After searching, I learned some of compiler optimization. This is called Dead codes elimination(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination). Most compiler will do this. In my case, the gcc does it under linux with -o option and I compile the codes with VS2010 under DEBUG modes which do not do the dead code elimination. ps: -fdce is the actual option in gcc to do the dead code elimination.

Comment: @xhfz007 Usually compilers don't perform (almost) any optimization in DEBUG builds (that's the _meaning_ of "debug" configuration, a set of options to make debugging easier,optimizations usually mess-up generated code enough to make debug much much harder).

Comment: Make sure proper optimization options are set for your project. This will possibly recognize and eliminate the dead code.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, most compilers are capable of taking care of that kind of the *dead* code, effectively removing that particular instruction / block. However, AFAIK it is not *guaranteed* and may differ between compilers and / or supplied optimization level settings.

However, if you want this to be handled in the preprocessing state itself (should be a better approach, IMHO, as `ARCH_ARM` is a MACRO), you can make use of `#if` preprocessor statements, to remove the dependency on compiler optimization level.

For example, in general

```
void ff_dcadsp_init(DCADSPContext *s)
{
    //something common code

    #if ARCH_ARM                 //this {#if...#endif} block 
        ff_dcadsp_init_arm(s);   //only get compiled if ARCH_ARM evaluates to non-zero
    #endif

   //something more common code
}
```

Comment: @onemasse well, `#if` as used in currect form, should also work, IMHO.

Comment: @onemasse: No, this should work. Code between `#if ARCH_ARM` and `#endif` will be compiled only if `ARCH_ARM` is `#define`d to non-zero value. And in case of `#ifdef ARCH_ARM` <code> `#endif`, the code will be executed even if `ARCH_ARM` is `#define`d to `0`

Comment: Can anybody be kind enough to explain the reason behind the downvote? What did I miss, please? (except the `#ifdef` part, which may be confusing in _this_ scenario, already removed).

Answer (score 2):

If `ARCH_ARM` is a macro, you'd probably be better off with something like:

```
void ff_dcadsp_init(DCADSPContext *s)
{
    s->lfe_fir = dca_lfe_fir_c;
    #if ARCH_ARM != 0
        ff_dcadsp_init_arm(s);
    #endif
}
```

Then you don't *have* to concern yourself with what an optimiser will do. The C standard itself doesn't mandate that "dead" code is removed, this is totally down to how each implementation wants to do it.

The use of standard C functionality like `#if` *is* mandated by the standard, and therefore much more portable.

Comment: yeah, #if is a good choice, but that codes come from the ffmpeg source codes, and it goes well under linux.

Comment: This is from the ffmpeg source code, see https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/1.1/dcadsp_8c_source.html. I don't know why it hasn't been done properly, I traced the commit that added that part back to April 2010, from Måns Rullgård, one of the major FFmpeg contributors.

Comment: Not using a `#if` will ensure the code compiles whatever the value of the macro is. Any decent compiler will generate no code for the if statement.

Comment: @ouah, your definition of "any decent compiler" seems to not match the definition that ISO gives to a "C compiler".  There is _zero_ requirement for a compiler to remove dead code, there is 100% requirement for it to remove code inside the `#if/#endif` directives. The whole _point_ of the question is predicated on that fact.

Comment: @paxdiablo I agree with you it's not mandatory for a compiler to perform any _optimization_. That said it's reasonable to assume compiler does them and in this case it's a **micro-optimization** we usually rant to avoid (removing an unnecessary condition, and removing a function body for a function used for **initialization**) that I'd don't even bother if compiler let it there. BTW OP seems surprised because ff_dcadsp_init_arm() is in object file (he is not checking if dead-code is compiled or not) and **preprocessor directives won't change compiler behavior** here.